# Database Schema design for payroll

Tags: database-design, schema

I want to create the schema for this database design for a payroll system . What i don't understand is how to join the deductions to make a salary and then join salary to an employee. See my [schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5m78u.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You should start by going through the references [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_intro.asp) or [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256235(v=vs.110).aspx) on XML schema. The idea is that you want to create a *Salary* element with *Total* amount and *Federal* tax deduction elements. First you define the basic elements `Total` and `Federal` along these lines.

```
<xs:element name="Federal" type="xs:double"/>
<xs:element name="Total" type="xs:double"/>
```

You can restrict the total salary and federal tax data to be in a range with min and max limits. Then you would create *Salary* type as

```
<xs:element name="Salary">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:element ref="Total" maxOccurs="1"/>   <!-- use Total only once -->
    <xs:element ref="Federal" maxOccurs="1"/> <!-- use Federal only once -->
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

The actual data would look like this:

```
<xs:Salary>
  <xs:Total>50000.00</xs:Total>
  <xs:Federal>10000.00</xs:Federal>
</xs:Salary>
```

Thus you would keep building up the elements as per its requirement. Also google *xs:simpleType* and *xs:complexType* for detailed explanation on, and creation of *reusable* types. This [page](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_complextype.asp) has examples on creating complex types.